# Multi-scoring with GridSearchCV

Tags: python, grid-search

i am trying to do multiscoring with GridSearchCv but i am getting nan values.Can someone explain?

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from collections import defaultdict
from sklearn.metrics import adjusted_rand_score
from sklearn.metrics import adjusted_mutual_info_score,normalized_mutual_info_score,homogeneity_score
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

import warnings
from sklearn.exceptions import ConvergenceWarning

scoring_metrics={'RS':make_scorer(adjusted_rand_score) , 'MI':make_scorer(adjusted_mutual_info_score),'AMI':make_scorer(adjusted_mutual_info_score),
                 'NMI':make_scorer(normalized_mutual_info_score),'Homogeneity':make_scorer(homogeneity_score)}

parameters={'eps':[5, 5.5, 6, 6.5 ,7],'min_samples':list(range(5,10))}

dbscan=DBSCAN()

grid_search=GridSearchCV(dbscan,parameters,scoring=scoring_metrics,refit='RS',cv=5)
grid_search.fit(X,y)

best_params = grid_search.best_params_
print("Best Parameters:", best_params)
for scorer_name, scorer_fnc in scoring_metrics.items():
  best_score=grid_search.best_score_
  print(f'best_score_{scorer_name}',best_score)
```

i am getting tis answer
Best Parameters: {'eps': 5, 'min_samples': 5}
best_score_RS nan
best_score_MI nan
best_score_AMI nan
best_score_NMI nan
best_score_Homogeneity nan

Comment: Since DBSCAN does not have a `predict` method, did you try specifiying `response_method` in `make_scorer`? Also, perhaps you can show the output of the grid-search-cv with `verbose` set to 3?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @stochastic13  now i unterstand why DBSCAN fails. I will try to do the verbose and see the results. Thank you!!